# Drupal убрать дату и автора из выдачи

Tags: drupal

Надо убрать дату и автора из выдачи google.com. Подскажите кто встречался с этой проблемой

Comment: убери это со страниц, исчезнет и из выдачи

Comment: как убрать? Подскажешь

Comment: слишком общий вопрос